# How to get taxonomy contextual filters working by name for users?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, users

I have users sorted by taxonomy. I created a page, added a field to a contextual filter and it works, but by ID only. I want user friendly paths, so I need it to work by name. All solutions I've seen was for nodes, where contextual filter is `Taxonomy:`. There is no `Taxonomy:` filters category for users, i need to use `User: field_name` and I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to add the Taxonomy field you associated with the user as a relationship, and then filter on that.